# jQuery $(document).bind only apply when links in a certain div clicked

Tags: jquery, binding

I'm creating a page where multiple links will open a [facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/) (lightbox style div).

For links on the page within the `#artworks-col` div, I want the facebox to be forced to open at 800px width; for all others, I just want it to use its default calculations.

Putting this on the page forces all links to open it as 800px wide:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).bind('beforeReveal.facebox', function() { $('#facebox .content').css('width', '800'); });
</script>
```

But after multiple attempts to make it apply to only links within `#artworks-col`, I can still only have it apply to all or none. Is there a way of filtering this bind event to be specific to that subset of links?

The only way I've thought of being able to do this would be to set a temporary flag using `$("a#artworks-col").click(var flag = true);` and check that flag in the document-wide bind event (and clear it in the bind event after running the width modification) but that seems really messy, and there's bound to be a better way of going about this.

Here's the RoR view for this page (note that the script will be moved to an external file once this is working, it's just easier to have it all in one place for now):

```
<div id="admin_logo">
    <%= image_tag("logo_admin.png", alt: "Administration") %>
</div>
<div id="artworks-col"><%= render partial: "artworks_list" %></div>
<div id="artists-col"><%= render partial: "artists_list" %></div>
<div id="locations-col"><%= render partial: "locations_list" %></div>
<div id="insurers-col"><%= render partial: "insurers_list" %></div>
<div id="users-col"><%= render partial: "users_list" %></div>

<div id="show-object" style="display:none;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).bind('beforeReveal.facebox', function() { $('#facebox .content').css('width', '800'); });
</script>
```

The render partial's in the erb code above just add a list of `<a href>`'s for all the objects of that type in the database. Those links are the ones I want to apply this functionality to.

**EDIT**

As I can't get this to work through jQuery as I wanted it to, I'm going to put a workaround in place using CSS to define a div of width 800px to be displayed when those specific links are clicked. I'd prefer to do this through jQuery because it would be used in other situations where a more dynamic approach is required, but this will have to do for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDITED: WORKING ANSWER

I have uploaded a working version of the example here: http://fluidev.com/stack/fbox/test.html

This is how you'll go about binding seperate click events and achieve different widths for each.  Through the use of a callback function (a function that runs after the initial calling function is completed) we can achieve the illusion of different set widths, even though it happens after the facebox loads.  What's cool about this is that you can even use animations and stuff to change the widths if you want!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#artworks-col").bind("click", function() {
            $.facebox({ div: '#artworks-col' }, function() { $('#facebox .content').css('width', '800px'); } ); 
        });
        $("#artists-col").bind("click", function() {
            $.facebox({ div: '#artists-col' }, function() { $('#facebox .content').css('width', '200px'); } ); 
        });
    });
```

Comment: I have tried this, though I tried with your example as well. Unfortunately, this doesn't work, even without the `#(document).bind...`, just having the `$("artworks-col a".bind...` doesn't take effect when clicking links in that div.

Comment: you could also try using the .on() function mentioned in a previous answer attempt.  Also make sure there is only one instance of that specific ID on the page.  Showing some HTML would help a lot with this one as I'm fairly confident this should have worked for you.

Comment: You should ensure the elements being selected and bound to exist when the script is being called...I would wrap the above code in a $(document).ready() call...still investigating the facebox code (I've never seen it before)

Comment: I've tried putting all of yours in a `$(document).ready(function() { your_code_here })` call and even the first call for `$(document).bind` then has no effect.

Comment: i hope you havent run off to do your css hack, this will work! =O

Comment: That is fantastic, thanks! I was going to look at doing dynamic resizing while it was open down the track as well, so this will help me a long way towards that.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your markup, I can only assume you mean something like this:

```
$(document).bind('beforeReveal.facebox', function () {
    $('#facebox .content').css('width', 'auto');
});
$('div#artworks-col a').click(function (e) {
    $('#facebox .content').css('width', '800px');
});
//Try doing this instead, but I suspect links outside $('div#artworks-col a')
//will also set the width to 800px...
$('#facebox .content').bind('beforeReveal.facebox', function () {
    $('#facebox .content').css('width', '800px');
});
```

Comment: This is close to what I want, the issue with this however is that the first time the links inside `div#artworks-col a` are clicked, the width doesn't apply; after the facebox is closed and re-opened using that link, the width then applies.

Comment: Ok, updated answer with a quick/hacky fix. I could probably be far more elegant if I knew more about the structure of your markup... :)

Comment: What other markup would you like to see?
Unfortunately, this one also didn't work.  Only the `$(document).bind` call has any effect.

Comment: Updated answer. The rough structure of the document, including where `#facebox` is defined (no need to include what your partials render, unless one of them renders `#facebox`) would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Use the .on() which available in jQuery 1.7 and above..

```
$(document).on('beforeReveal.facebox','#artworks-col', function() { 

              $('#facebox .content').css('width', '800'); 
 });
```

Looks like you have multiple elements with the same id in your page.. Try using a class instead..

Comment: This didn't have any effect on the width of the object, though I'll read more on the `.on()` function later.